# Screen's real size is bigger than what i see objective C Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When I make a new project on Xcode and use the Game Template then I get this Spaceship Game. I just made an easy Code to see if it works to add elements, but it seems that the real size of the screen is bigger than what I see. When I draw a `SKSpirtenode` on x and y = 0 or x and y = 10, it's not on the screen, it's somewhere outside the screen. When I let a ball bounce, the ball goes off the screen and comes back, so it seems somewhere is an end but I would like to fix that problem. I don't want to fix it with using specific numbers to set the screen because I want my app to run on an iPhone 6 and an iPhone 5 as well. Also, I'd like to make it work for Portrait and Landscape Mode.

Here is my Code, I'm just adding an abstract object.

Here is my view controller.m

```
    @implementation SKScene (Unarchive)

+ (instancetype)unarchiveFromFile:(NSString *)file {
    /* Retrieve scene file path from the application bundle */
    NSString *nodePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file ofType:@"sks"];
    /* Unarchive the file to an SKScene object */
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:nodePath
                                          options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe
                                            error:nil];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *arch = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    [arch setClass:self forClassName:@"SKScene"];
    SKScene *scene = [arch decodeObjectForKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey];
    [arch finishDecoding];

    return scene;
}

@end

@implementation GameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    GameScene *scene = [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"GameScene"];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

**gamescene.m**

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene


-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.29 green:0.75 blue:.99 alpha:1];
    SKSpriteNode *platform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor brownColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 20)];
    platform.position = CGPointMake(50, 100);
    [self addChild:platform];

}


-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```

I've read that i can add something like

`scene = GameScene(self.view.frame.size)`

but I dont know where and I couldn't find out.

Id be happy if u can help me!